# Bootstrap Modals, - takes way too long to load, since webpage went live

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a wierd situation, where my webpage used to load just fine, before I put it online with hosting and domain. Now the Modal, that's supposed to popup on click, takes so long to load (in particularly through safari, firefox and IOS) that it undermines the whole purpose of the page. And so it's a real problem. At this point it seems to load just fine in chrome though.

I have tried several things, for example thoroughly checking my FTP-client, deleting, editing code, re-uploading but at this point, nothing has worked. Can anyone offer some insight as to where I go wrong?

```
window.onload = function() {
    const span = document.querySelectorAll(".PopUp");
    span.forEach(LIelm => {
        LIelm.addEventListener('click', showHideModal)
    })
};

function showHideModal(e) {
    const projectNode = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    if (!projectNode.matches('.Project, .modal-content')) return;
    e.preventDefault();

    if (projectNode.matches('.Project')) {
        document.getElementById(projectNode.dataset.modal).style.display = "block";
    } else {
        projectNode.parentNode.style.display = "";
    }
}

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script src="ModalPopUp.js"></script>
</head>



<body>
    <div class="content">
        <ul style="list-style: none;">
            <li class="Project" data-modal="myModal_1">
                <span id="myBtn_1">
                    Lirma Type
                </span>
                <span id="year">
                    2019
                </span>

                <div class="Describtion">
                    <p>Typedesign</p>

                    <br>

                    <span class="PopUp">Images</id>
                </div>

                <div id="myModal_1" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                            <!-- The slideshow -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="carousel-item active">    
                                    <img src="Images/Lirma/type.jpg" alt="img" width="100%">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="ModalHide.js"></script>
<script src="pExpand.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to  your website?

Comment: http://cthornval.com, when clicking a project it expands and then you're supposed to click "images".

Comment: When I visit the page, almost 150 MB of images get loaded. The script at the end waits until the entire page is loaded, so until then, the popups don't work as intended (clicking "images" simply closes the project again). It works "fine" offline because the images are all right there on your hard drive so the popup script runs instantly. (also, your HMTL is invalid. you're closing a span with `</id>` at one point, and your scripts belong at the end but inside of `<body>`, nothing can be outside)

Comment: The fix is to lazy-load the images: insert them dynamically into the popup when the project is opened. And try to reduce their sizes a bit, a bunch of them have more then 5MB, some even more than 10MB.

Comment: Hey @Chris G! This sounds spot on and I am currently working on it. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

What seems to take so long to load are the images so I see in Chrome it does not take so long because it is using the cache memory if you clean it and run it again it takes about 20 seconds

1.-[chrome no cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84oON.png)

2.-[chrome cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjs7c.png)

Try using an image compressor to reduce weight and improve download time
https://compressjpeg.com/es/